# Remove Button to configure in Table (editable) cloned rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an [editable table with rows cloned](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/S3kZw/5/), the rows cloned are editable in both column with a *text area* and *input number*. If you click to edit the input number, there is a function which makes the sum and gives the Total Amount automatically.

My issue now is that i can not configure properly the remove button for the rows cloned. If you give a try you notice that instead of removing a row, it adds one more. Please i need help on how to figure it out this issue.

This is the script for rows cloned, i think it needs to get reduced and improved

```
$('input:button').live('click',function(){
    var temprow = $('#temprow tbody').html();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.after(temprow);
});

$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var lastid = $('[id^="sum"]').length + 1;
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $clone.attr('id', 'sum' + lastid)
    $tr.after($clone);
    initEditables();
    tally('p#subtotal');
    tally('p#total');
});

$(".tr_clone_remove").live("click", function() {
$(".tr_clone").last().remove();
    initEditables();
    tally('p#subtotal');
    tally('p#total');
});

initEditables();
tally('p#subtotal');
tally('p#total');
```

[My Table](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/S3kZw/5/)

Comment: It's because `.tr_clone_remove` is a button as well and when it's clicked, the function bound to `input:button` is fired instead.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/S3kZw/8/

Comment: `live` is deprecated. You could use `on` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this was ok but when i clone the row clicking the add button , it get the previous one that i edit and not the original one with the placeholder click to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the `tr.after` function to:

   ```
   if ($(this).val() == '+') {
       tr.after(temprow);
   }
   ```
2. Make the `remove()` call as:

   ```
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   ```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3kZw/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Edited your Fiddle with the correct solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/S3kZw/5/

- Since the `tr_clone_remove` class is also a button type input, the first handler is called every time you click on the remove button.

  ```
  $('input:button').live('click',function(){
      var temprow = $('#temprow tbody').html();
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      tr.after(temprow);
  });
  ```

  This is the reason why rows are being inserted, instead of being deleted.
- Also, updated your remove row block with the correct code.